# Freeze dynamic table columns without an ugly loop and fixed widths/left values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sticky

I have a table where I want to freeze the header row and n amount of columns. I got it working pretty well, but on a large table it's painfully slow. Is there a better way of achieving the same result? I tried `$(this).position().left+'px'` instead of `freezePos` but it seemed to make it even slower (any tool out there where I can A/B the speed?).

It seems ugly to calculate the positions. I wish I could just lock the cells on the x axis without setting a `left`. It also forces me to use fixed widths on those cells which is not ideal. What else can I do to improve this?

There is no css `position: fixed-x` right?

```js
$.fn.freezeColumns = function() {
  var freezePos = 0;
  $('thead th').each(function(index, val) {
    if(index == 2) return false; // Exit after n elements
    var $self = $(this);
    var curWidth = $self.outerWidth();
    $('th:nth-child(' + parseInt(index+1) + '), td:nth-child(' + parseInt(index+1) + ')').addClass('sticky').css('left', freezePos);
    freezePos += curWidth;
  });
};
$(document).freezeColumns();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande';
}

div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 2px 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

thead th {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: #146775;
  color: white;
  z-index: 3;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
}
th.sticky {
  z-index: 4;
}
td.sticky {
  background: #569CA8;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Header 1 Title</th>
        <th>Header 2 Title X</th>
        <th>Header 3 Title XX</th>
        <th>Header 4 Title XXX</th>
        <th>Header 5 Title XXXX</th>
        <th>Header 7 Title XXXXX</th>
        <th>Header 8 Title XXXXXX</th>
        <th>Header 9 Title XXXXXXX</th>
        <th>Header 10 Title XXXXXXX</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td>Column 10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td>Column 10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td>Column 10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td>Column 10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td>Column 10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td>Column 10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td>Column 10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td>Column 10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td>Column 10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td>Column 10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td>Column 10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td>Column 10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td>Column 10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td>Column 10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td>Column 10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td>Column 10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td>Column 10</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: If you relay on sticky, then you only might have to update the left value for the cell of the second column (`tr :nth-child(2)`)  css example where this value is to be found https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oJKova  .... unless column 1 has a a known and fixed width

Comment: Thanks! Problem is that it's dynamic so you can choose where you want to set the freeze point. I should have mentioned that closer instead of just typing `// Exit after n elements`. Also in your example the second column moves slightly to the left when scrolling so not 100% sticky. At least in FF where I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't even bother freezing the elements (if I understand correctly what your going for). Rather create a function that clones N number of rows along with the header and position them absolutely over the originals.  Maybe throw an invisibility filter on the originals if needed.

EDIT:

I was looking at the code again.  You could pick up some performance gains by moving as much as the common attributes outside of the jquery loop.  Something like this:

```
$.fn.newFreeze = function(num) {
  var left = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i < num + 1; i++) {
    left += i === 1 ? 0 : $(`th:nth-child(${i - 1})`).outerWidth();
    $(`th:nth-child(${i}),td:nth-child(${i})`).each(function() {
      $(this).css({
        left,
        zIndex: 4,
      })
    })
  }
}
```

```
th, td {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but my tables are so dynamic (and big and heavy) that it was impossible to match the height and widths of the cloned table cells. And when scrolling it looked really ugly and out of sync before they catched up. How is google sheets solving this? I've hard to believe that they clone the whole table over the other?

Comment: I doubt Google sheets is actually using a table.  If accessibility isn't an issue, you could recreate the table with flexbox and prob get better performance. Dom manipulation is hard on browsers and harder on mobile.  Screen readers won't know how to handle a flexbox table structure either.

Comment: on the above edit, you'd have to change some styling classes as well.

Comment: Thank you! But isn't having even more each()es even worse for performance? Is there a tool where I can run the two against each other?

Comment: try this and let me know how they perform: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now

Comment: Cool. Will try! I'll be back.

Comment: Hm, difference seems really slim. I moved as much as possible to css and the rest with jQuery.